# Laravel retrieving eloquent nested eager loading

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

In my application i have 4 models that relate to each other.

```
Forms->categories->fields->triggers
```

What I am trying to do is get the Triggers that refer to the current Form.

Upon researching i found nested eager loading, which would require my code to look like this

```
Form::with('categories.fields.triggers')->get();
```

Looking through the response of this i can clearly see the relations all the way down to my desired triggers.

Now the part I'm struggling with is only getting the triggers, without looping through each model.

The code i know works:

```
$form = Form::findOrFail($id);

$categories = $form->categories;
foreach ($categories as $category) {
    $fields = $category->fields;
    foreach ($fields as $field) {
        $triggers[] = $field->triggers;
    }
}
```

I know this works, but can it be simplified? Is it possible to write:

```
$form = Form::with('categories.fields.triggers')->get()

$triggers = $form->categories->fields->triggers;
```

To get the triggers related? Doing this as of right now results in:

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$categories
```

Since it is trying to run the `$form->categories` on a collection.

How would i go about doing this? Do i need to use the `HasManyThrough` relation on my models?

**My models**

```
class Form extends Model
{   
    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Category');
    }
}


class Category extends Model
{
    public function form()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Form');
    }

    public function fields()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Field');
    }
}

class Field extends Model
{
    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
    }

    public function triggers()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Trigger');
    }
}

class Trigger extends Model
{
    public function fields()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Field');
    }
}
```

The triggers run through a pivot table, but should be reachable with the same method?

Answer (score 0):

I created a `HasManyThrough` relationship with unlimited levels and support for `BelongsToMany`:
[Repository on GitHub](https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep)

After the installation, you can use it like this:

```php
class Form extends Model {
    use \Staudenmeir\EloquentHasManyDeep\HasRelationships;

    public function triggers() {
        return $this->hasManyDeep(Trigger::class, [Category::class, Field::class, 'field_trigger']);
    }
}

Form::with('triggers')->get();
Form::findOrFail($id)->triggers;
```